# Automatic Parameter with Current Month and Year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I need to have a parameter auto-populate with the current month and year. I have got it working now but I have to manually input the month.

```
[Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&[9]
```

I have tried this

```
[Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&Month("M",-0,now())
```

That shows correct as an expression but does nothing in my parameter.

My outcome will show in the dropdown as default like this

```
2019-9
```

Comment: right click on the parameter, jump to default... select default value type in the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on parameter and go to default into the expression. There will be something like this:

```
=[Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&[9]
```

Now replace this expression with the following expression:

```
=[Date YMD].[Month].&[" & CStr(Year(Now())) & "]&[9] 
'This means [Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&[9]

=[Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&[" & CStr(Month(Now())) & "]"
'This means [Date YMD].[Month].&[2019]&[9]
```

And now when you change both a little bit:

```
=[Date YMD].[Month].&[" & CStr(Year(Now())-1) & "]&[" & CStr(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now()))) & "]" 
'This means [Date YMD].[Month].&[2018]&[8]
```

And so on...I think you will get it.